# Rails: How to find out what query is being run in SQL when a page loads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to know what queries are being run when a User is interacting with different pages on the website? I'd also like to know how long each query took. How and where can I see that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a log folder in every `rails` application with a `.log` file for each of the environment you've run your application in. You'll see these kind of stats in it:

```
Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-29 11:09:47 -0400
Served asset /jquery.js - 200 OK (3ms)

Started GET "/users/auth/google/callback?_method=post&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud&openid.response_nonce=2012-10-26T19%3A29%3A52ZkvQlFeFr5Rk78g&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback%3F_method%3Dpost&openid.assoc_handle=AMlYA9VjNZ-QIIMe5bhvtPLBsAdm5xMltOa7MEwUoW4Opx9tXd_khhcS&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle%2Cns.ext1%2Cext1.mode%2Cext1.type.ext2%2Cext1.value.ext2%2Cext1.type.ext0%2Cext1.value.ext0%2Cext1.type.ext3%2Cext1.value.ext3&openid.sig=ehFAJ1m8nPces8%2Bj6Ud%2FicpuohY%3D&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawljL9RKBE7iUQHk94UhJQ-4sDOTawUfpNc&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawljL9RKBE7iUQHk94UhJQ-4sDOTawUfpNc&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_response&openid.ext1.type.ext2=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Ffirst&openid.ext1.value.ext2=Fernando&openid.ext1.type.ext0=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ext1.value.ext0=fernando%40findhorsesforsale.net&openid.ext1.type.ext3=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Flast&openid.ext1.value.ext3=Mendez" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-26 15:29:52 -0400

Started GET "/run_dates/current_pdf_generation_status.js?pdf_generation_id=e3ef90b05844012f4fc2723c91dfe57c&_=1332637701414" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-24 21:08:29 -0400
Processing by RunDatesController#current_pdf_generation_status as JS
  Parameters: {"pdf_generation_id"=>"e3ef90b05844012f4fc2723c91dfe57c", "_"=>"1332637701414"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  RunDate Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "run_dates".* FROM "run_dates" WHERE (pdf_generation_id = 'e3ef90b05844012f4fc2723c91dfe57c') LIMIT 1
  Rendered run_dates/current_pdf_generation_status.js.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 2.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **development.log** if you are in development mode, it will show you all the queries with the time taken to ran that query. For production, see **production.log** and for staging look at **staging.log**

You can delete that file rails will create it again if you want to look at specific queries. but i would suggest instead of deleting, when you are hitting the page, print something different like '-----------------' that will differentiate other queries from the queries of the page you want to see.

Comment: There are a lot of queries in there already.Is there some way to clear the file so I can track from scratch?

Comment: @pratski: just delete the log file. Rails will create a new one. I don't think in production mode queries get logged though. This only works in development.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the User, you can use some browser plugin (e.g. Firebug)

[image]

If you are not the user, you can check the log to see what queries are done.

Comment: @Mischa No, it does ! I use Firebug for it all days. It returns urls, params, their time, their order, their size, their method, their errors codes, their headers...

Comment: Yes, but not the **database queries**. This question is specifically about queries. Those can't be **never** be seen by the user, unless you have a very serious security flaw.

Comment: @Mischa True... But you must admit that the question is not so well asked : 'I want to know what queries are being run when a User is interacting with different pages on the website?'

Comment: No, I don't admit that. It talks clearly talks about queries. I actually think the question is quite clear.

Comment: @Mischa In french, 'query' and 'request' are defined by the same word. That's confusing. http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1586172&langid=6

Comment: Stop fighting guys. The question has been resolved. And thats what matters. Thanks Mischa for having my back! :p